# Проверка поля и вывод разных шаблонов MODX MIGX

Tags: modx, pdo, migx, pdoresource

У меня есть 3 поля: name, price, link в TV tablepriceitem

Мне нужно проверять на заполненность поле link и в зависимости от этого выводить разные шаблоны. Я делаю так:

```html
[[getImageList? 
&docid=`[[*id]]` 
&tvname=`tablepriceitem` 
&tpl=`[[+linkitem:is=`0`:then=`link.tpl`:else=`link2.tpl`]]` 
]]
```

Но у меня проверка не срабатывает. Почему? Буду благодарен за подсказку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к `linkitem`, как к [плэйсхолдеру](https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/tag-syntax), коим `tv-параметр` в данном случаи не является. Запись должна быть такой:

```
[[*linkitem:is=`0`:then=`link.tpl`:else=`link2.tpl`]]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Александр, можно Вас попросить помочь мне с выводом MIGX полей дочерних ресурсов ? Я создам отдельную тему..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673805/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-migx-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-pdoresource здесь создал вопрос