# Вывод параметров MIGX через pdoresource

Tags: modx, migx, pdoresource

У меня есть дополнительное поле MIGX с названием tablepriceitem , в нем содержатся такие параметры: priceitem , nameitem, linkitem

Это дополнительное поле присвоено дочерним ресурсам, мне нужно вывести поля дочерних ресурсов на родительский. Пишу код вот так, но он не срабатывает, хотя по логике всё верно:

```html
 [[pdoResources?
&depth=`0`
&includeTVs=`tablepriceitem`   
&processTVs=`1`
&idx=`1`
&tpl=`@INLINE <div>[[+pagetitle]] [[+id]] [[+tv.priceitem]] [[+tv.nameitem]] [[+tv.linkitem]] </div>`
 ]]
```

Ошибка при проверке в tpl и так же не выводится id страницы из которой взяты поля:

```html
[[!getImageList? 
&tvname=`tablepriceitem` 
&tpl=`@CODE: [[+linkitem:isnot=``:then=`это первая строка [[+id]]`:else=`это не первая строка`]]` &docid=`[[+id]]` ]]
```

Comment: Попробуйте в `&tpl` при вызове `pdoResources` указать чанк, в котором будет вызываться `getImageList` с параметром `&docid` (помимо обязательных `tvname`. `tpl`), в который надо поместить `[[+id]]`. Дальше уже на Ваш вкус. Если что-то не получится дополните вопрос тем, что пробовали.

Comment: Всё сделал как и написали, работает, спасибо! Только почему-то проверка не работает... наверное ошибка в синтаксисе:
дополнил вопрос. Если не сложно, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: И можно ли как-то выводить эти результаты не подряд? Чтобы из каждого дочернего ресурса они шли в отдельный блок...